# Using undo stack for a command which is running asynchronously and is emitting signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots, qprocess

I have a command inherited from `QUndoCommand`:

```cpp
class ImportEntityCommand : public QUndoCommand
{
    // ...

private:
    QString m_importedEntityName;
    Importer *m_importer;
    // ...
}
```

The `redo` method kicks off a QProcess:

```cpp
void ImportEntityCommand::redo()
{
    if (/* Import is already done before */) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // Import finish is handled by a slot
        m_importer->import(m_url);
    }
}
```

Signal-slot connection is composed in command constructor:

```cpp
ImportEntityCommand::ImportEntityCommand(EditorSceneItemModel *sceneModel, const QUrl &url) :
  , m_importer(new Importer(/* ... */))
{

    // Importer would start a QProcess which runs asynchronously and emits a signal
    // that's why I have to handle the signal by a slot
    QObject::connect(m_importer
                     , &Importer::importFinished
                     , this
                     , &ImportEntityCommand::handleImportFinish
                     );
}
```

The signal emitted by the process is handled like this:

```cpp
void ImportEntityCommand::handleImportFinish(const QString name)
{
    m_importedEntityName = name;
}
```

But I'm receiving such error while compiling:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h:250: error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connectImpl(const QObject *,void **,const QObject *,void **,QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase *,Qt::ConnectionType,const int *,const QMetaObject *)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'const ImportEntityCommand *' to 'const QObject *'

The error point is that:

> cannot convert argument 3 from 'const ImportEntityCommand *' to 'const QObject *'

I'm inhering my `ImportEntityCommand` class from `QUndoCommand` <s>which in turn inherits from `QObject`, I guess.</s>

#### Question

Therefore, for some reason, Qt won't allow me to handle signals inside a command inherited from `QUndoCommand`.

- Is this limitation intentional?
- What are my options to work around this limitation? What is the standard procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm inhering my ImportEntityCommand class from QUndoCommand which in
> turn inherits from QObject, I guess.

QUndoCommand does not inherit from QObject see:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html

Compared to a QWidget for example, that does inherit from QObject.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html

If you want your importer to handle signals and slots you can just inherit from QObject:

```
class importer: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
private:
    ...
}
```

and you can connect to a lambda e.g.:

```
QObject::connect(m_importer
                 , &Importer::importFinished
                 [&]() { this->handleImportFinish() }
                 );
```

Comment: My `Importer` class already inherits from `QObject`. Actually, my `ImportEntityCommand` class is the problem cause which inherits from `QUndoCommand` and not `QObject`.

Comment: You can connect to a lambda which means `ImportEntityCommand` doesn't have to be a QObject, but then you'll have to handle the scope of the `ImportEntityCommand` and disconnect the connection when needed.

Comment: Right, lambda approach resolved the compile error. However, My app gets stuck while running which is probably due to some other problem. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use composition to place a QObject derived class instance in the ImportEntityCommand? You could then connect the signal to the QObject derived class which would then call in to ImportEntityCommand to do the work.

```
class SignalReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SignalReciever(ImportEntityCommand *iec) : QObject()
    , _iec(iec)
    {}
public slot:
    void handleImportFinished(QString url)
    {
        if (this->_iec) this->_iec->handleImportFinished(url);
    }
private:
    ImportEntityCommand *_iec{nullptr};
};
```

Then in your ImportEntityCommand, you would create a SignalReceiver and connect it to the signal:

```
class ImportEntityCommand : public QUndoCommand
{
    // ...same as before, then
private:
    QScopedPointer<SignalReceiver, QScopedPointerDeleteLater> _signalReceiver;
};
// in the ImportEntityCommand constructor
    this->_signalReceiver.reset(new SignalReceiver(this));
    QObject::connect(this->importer,
                     &Importer::importFinished,
                     this->_signalReciver.data(),
                     &SignalReceiver::handleImportFinished);
```

We can't get around from passing a raw pointer of `ImportEntityCommand` to `SignalReceiver` since `ImportEntityCommand` has to live in the undo stack. On the other hand, using a `QScopedPointer` for the receiver ensures that it is cleaned up properly when the undo stack deletes the `ImportEntityCommand` instance. Just remember to *always* specify the `QScopedPointerDeleteLater` when wrapping a `QObject` derivative -- especially one that is catching signals.

Comment: Eventually, I used your approach to be able to use signals/slots with my `QUndoCommand` instances. Thanks =)